# how to replace filter.phtml file in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, layout, catalog, xml, filter

How can i replace my

```
frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml
```

file to

```
frontend/base/default/template/checkbox/filter.phtml
```

in my layout **XML**

Comment: I think that this will be very difficult because `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml` calls `$this->getFilters()` which is declared in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php` which calls `$this->getChild` which children are set in the same file by `_prepareLayout` which gets the name of the blocks of the children by `_initBlocks` which are `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Category`, `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Decimal`, ... which extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract` and there is `$this->setTemplate('catalog/layer/filter.phtml');`. :)

Answer (score 1):

In this specific situation it would be easier to copy `frontend/base/default/template/catalog/layer/filter.phtml` to your theme and customize it there.

Comment: ya i know that but i need some different solution